# Faster methods of pattern matching DATES

Tags: regex, python-3.x, algorithm, pattern-matching, full-text-search

I'm doing pattern matching on **large** HTML documents. I currently have many handfuls of regex expressions I'm using to validate all kinds of dates `01-01-2000`, `1-1-2000`, `01/01/2000`, `01.01.2000`, `01/01/00`, `01 Jan 2000`... and so on. I can clean the HTML, this is not a problem nor is it something I'm currently caring about.

My current implementation is *"fine"*, because it works, but it's starting to take a good chunk of time, especially as every regex I have needs to run once on the document, not improving runtime OR efficiency.

Of course, my other options are using `dateutil` parser module or implementing an NLP technique (currently too much work).

I'm looking for an algorithm I can implement to speed this up. I briefly looked at the Aho-Corasick algorithm, which seems really good, but that seems to only be able to handle exact matches, or am I wrong? Are there similar algorithms more suited to pattern matching or am I stuck with regex?

Comment: For extracting patterned substrings from a larger string, regex is really the de facto. There are some regex implementations which support fewer features which could equate to better performance but it is likely that you would need to switch programming languages.

Comment: The other big question is whether you are running a single large regex or if your compiling multiple regexes against the same string. It could be wise to share your regex since certain people here really really know the ins and outs of regex performance.

Comment: What is meant by _validating dates_ ? Proper days of the month, years, leap years. Perhaps a date range

Comment: Is `01-01-2000` in `mm/dd/yyyy` format or `dd/mm/yyyy`?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus it's multiple different regexes. I basically run them each per document. Also I'm working in `dd/mm/yyyy` in general, but I'm trying to not account for this as most of my documents are EU based and hence 'dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: @x15 By validating I mean, as long as a "date" matches one of my above formats, then it's valid

Comment: @deskf4n I think they were asking whether your regex picks up or ignores `21/21/2000`. Does it properly distinguish the correct number of days in February during a leap year? If it's just extracting date-like structures then that is different than actually validating. Validating dates is a whole different beast compared to just extracting date-like structures. If your document has `45 Jan 3000` or `23 Jan 123` then what?

Comment: @x15 ah my bad. No, no actual validation like leap-years, just date like structures.

Comment: Regex is probably the right tool for the job and it sounds like you might need some optimization help. Soliciting software recommendations is an explicit reason to close a question.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus In that case I don't mind closing the question, although I would like to keep it open a while longer

Comment: I won't strong-arm you. It takes 5 votes to close a question.

Comment: Can't you combine your multiple regular expressions into one? For example, `"(dd?/dd?/dddd)|(dd?\s(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\sdddd)`' will match d/m/yyyy, d/mm/yyyy, dd/m/yyyy, dd/mm/yyyy, and dd mmm yyyy, etc.

Comment: @JimMischel I think `\d{1,2}(([\/.-])\d{1,2}\2| (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) )\d+` is probably closer to what OP needs. https://regex101.com/r/dxF7Wn/1

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thanks. I figure the regex can be optimized. The basic idea is to combine regexes so that he doesn't have to make multiple passes over the file.

Comment: @JimMischel I agree but at this point I'm trying to see how much I can optimize even this limited example. I'm down to [950 steps and 1ms](https://regex101.com/r/dz5O9p/1), heh. It used to be 3,500 steps and 4ms

Comment: @deskf4n Any thoughts about optimizing the regex instead?

Comment: @deskf4n Implementing the Aho-Corasick algorithm would not benefit you here. The regex matcher already uses a DFA similar to what Aho-Corasick does. You just have to combine your multiple regexes into one. It looks like MonkeyZeus is well on the way to doing that.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus oh hey I hadn't thought about the effect of combining multiple regexes into one. Are there any best ways/practices on optimizing or benchmarking regexes, beside the link you shared?

Comment: If you want generic regex optimization tips then just Google it. If you want specific feedback on your regex then you should share your regex in your question. Regex101 is the de-facto online regex tester for the Stack Overlfow regex tag because it provides everything you need to write and even optimize your regex as you type it. There are plenty of other online regex testers but none of them feel as complete as regex101. Besides, regex101 supports Python so its syntax and performance should match that of your environment.

Comment: If you choose to share your regex in your question or preferably start a new and on-topic question then make sure to provide samples of all the date formats which you are trying to capture.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus appreciated, thanks

Comment: You're welcome, good luck

Comment: If you've abandoned this question, then please close it.